# Dynamic prometheus labels in Gauge

Tags: go, prometheus

I wonder if/how it's possible to add dynamic labels. I don't know the key or the quantity of the labels which I would like to add to my gauge values.

**What I tried**

```
labelsContainers = []string{"node", "container", "pod", "qos", "namespace", "nodepool"}

// Requested resources
requestedContainerCPUCoresGauge = prometheus.NewGaugeVec(
    prometheus.GaugeOpts{
        Namespace: namespace,
        Subsystem: "pod_container_resource_requests",
        Name:      "cpu_cores",
        Help:      "Requested CPU cores in Kubernetes configuration",
    },
    labelsContainers)

for _, containerMetric := range containerMetrics {
    containerLabels := prometheus.Labels{
        "node":      containerMetric.Node,
        "container": containerMetric.Container,
        "qos":       containerMetric.Qos,
        "pod":       containerMetric.Pod,
        "namespace": containerMetric.Namespace,
    }

    for key, value := range containerMetric.NodeLabels {
        containerLabels[key] = value
    }

    requestedContainerCPUCoresGauge.With(containerLabels).Set(containerMetric.RequestedCPUCores)
    requestedContainerRAMBytesGauge.With(containerLabels).Set(containerMetric.RequestedMemoryBytes)
}
```

**The problem**

This throws a panic. I assume this is because the prom client expects exactly those labels defined in `labelsContainers` and doesn't allow further labels. How can I create a gauge which allows additional (unknown) labels?

Comment: This isn't possible in Prometheus. All measurements of a single metric must have the same label set.

Comment: Hm it's a pity. They would be the same everywhere, but I don't know their name and values before runtime.

Comment: In that case you can implement the [Collector interface](https://godoc.org/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus#Collector) yourself (take a look at the example to get started). Note that if the labels do change unexpectedly this will result in scrape errors.

Answer (score 1):

While the [github.com/prometheus/client_golang](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/prometheus/client_golang) library doesn't provide an easy way for specifying dynamic labels in metrics, this task can be easily achieved with [github.com/VictoriaMetrics/metrics](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/VictoriaMetrics/metrics) library via `GetOrCreate*()` functions + the usual `fmt.Sprintf()` for building dynamic labels. For example:

```golang
import (
        "fmt"
        "sort"
        "strings"

        "github.com/VictoriaMetrics/metrics"
)

// UpdateMetric updates metric `name{labels}` to the given value.
func UpdateMetric(name string, labels map[string]string, value float64) {
        // Construct `metric{labels}`
        var labelValues []string
        for k, v := range labels {
                labelValues = append(labelValues, fmt.Sprintf("%s=%q", k, v))
        }
        sort.Strings(labelValues)
        metricName := fmt.Sprintf("%s{%s}", name, strings.Join(labelValues, ","))

        // Update the counter
        metrics.GetOrCreateFloatCounter(metricName).Set(value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like this to initialise and return `GaugeVec` just once and then use it to assign dynamic label values to it.

```golang
type customMetrics struct {
    customMetricsOne  *prometheus.GaugeVec
    customMetricsTwo  *prometheus.GaugeVec
    Initialized       bool
}

func newCustomMetrics() (m *customMetrics) {
    m = &customMetrics{
        customMetricsOne: prometheus.NewGaugeVec(
        prometheus.GaugeOpts{
            Name:      "metric_name",
            Help:      "Metric Help Doc, can be skipped",
        }, []string{"label1", "label2"}),
        customMetricsTwo: prometheus.NewGaugeVec(
        prometheus.GaugeOpts{
            Name:      "metric_two_name",
            Help:      "Metric Help Doc, can be skipped",
        }, []string{"label3", "label4"}),
    }

    prometheus.MustRegister(
        m. customMetricsOne,
        m. customMetricsTwo,
    )
    m.Initialized = true

    return m
}


func main() {
    if !cm.Initialized {
        cm = *newCustomMetrics()
    }

    cm.customMetricsOne.With(prometheus.Labels{"label1": "label1 value", "label2": "label2 value"}).Set(20.45)
    cm.customMetricsTow.With(prometheus.Labels{"label3": "label3 value", "label4": "label4 value"}).Set(40.45)
}
```